# Iterate list and dictionary at the same time Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary(k) and a list(l)

```py
k = [
    {'x': 2.5, 'y': 1.5, 'z': 2},
    {'x': 3, 'z': -1.5},
]

l = [-9, -2, -4, 1, 4, 7]
```

What will be the easiest way to iterate k and z so together so that we can compute a formula for example using these values?

So far I have been using:

```
for dic in k:
    for key in dic:
        print(dic[key])
```

But this only iterates `k` alone. I need both `k` and `z` to iterate together so that we can use subsequent values to compute a function.

Output expected to compute a function for every values:

```py
x + y*l + z*l*l
```

`x,y,z` will be `0` where it is not present

Comment: what happens when `l` is not present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import itertools

k = [
    {'x': 2.5, 'y': 1.5, 'z': 2},
    {'x': 3, 'z': -1.5},
]

l = [-9, -2, -4, 1, 4, 7]


for d, i in itertools.zip_longest(k, l, fillvalue={}):
    x = d.get('x', 0)
    y = d.get('y', 0)
    z = d.get('z', 0)
    print(x + y*i + z*i*i)
```

output:

```
151.0
-3.0
0
0
0
0
```

constraint: `l` has to always be longer than `k`.

Comment: Why not just `zip`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for dic, l in zip(k, z):
    x, y, z = dic.get(‘x’, 0), dic.get(‘y’, 0), dic.get(‘z’, 0)
    return x + y*l + z*l*l
```